Radio mic and speaker as camera mic input

I want to add radio comms to in car action camera audio. I am a total amateur in analog circuits. I understand that i can't just feed headphone out and mic into camera. That will trip PTT (Push-to-Talk) on the radio and levels will be way different. Also need to add another external mic to capture in car sound. Radio mic is inside helmet and has noise cancelling. Ideal situation would be to lower car mic level once PTT is pressed and capture helmet mic even if PTT is not pressed. Drivers make comments without transmission sometimes.
How can I prevent audio from an external microphone from being fed into the car radio?
Any tips on design. Radio wiring diagram attached.
I will have to feed +5V to camera, so power is available for any relays or other clever circuitry.
